# UWP: Redefining Button Styles

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to modify the color of my Button by defining styles for light and dark modes.I have a style defined as follows :

```
<Style x:Key="ExampleButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
</Style>
```

In another file, I have defined the ButtonBackground to "Red" in light mode. My expectation is that when my app uses this ExampleButton, it should have a red background. However, i can still see this button using its default BorderBackground which is SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush. I can get around this issue in 3 ways :

1. Redefine SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush to "Red" which works but I might use SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush for other Controls so don't want to use this approach.
2. Add another setter to the above code and have something like this

   ```
    <Style x:Key="ExampleButton" TargetType="Button">
      <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
      <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
   </Style>
   ```
3. Edit the values in the Button Template

Which would be the most elegant solution to achieve this ? Is there a better solution other than the 3 i have described above?

I am looking to avoid adding entire templates to modify the colors

Comment: How about your progress? If your issue has been solved, you could mark useful answer, which will help others that face the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way indeed would be to define a `SolidColorBrush` that differs depending on the app theme. First you should add a `ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries` to your `Application.Resources` or `Page.Resources` like so. Then you set this `SolidColorBrush` as the value of the `BackGround` property of your button style, like so:

```xml
<Page
    ....
    RequestedTheme="Light">
    <!--Red button, or set to "Dark" for a blue button, remove this line or set to "Auto" to choose device theme-->
    
    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomButtonBackGroundColor" Color="Red"/>
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomButtonBackGroundColor" Color="Blue"/>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>

            <Style x:Key="ExampleButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource CustomButtonBackGroundColor}"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>
</Page>
```

Then you can add your button like this:

```xml
<Button Content="Example Button" Style="{StaticResource ExampleButtonStyle}"/>
```

Comment: If I have <Setter Property="Background" Value="{BorderBrush}"> Is there a way to just set BorderBrush ={ThemeResource CustomButtonBackGroundColor"} Here BorderBrush is  the default for Button styles.

Comment: The problem I am facing is that in the Style Template, BorderBrush points to SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush . If I set BorderBrsuh to {ThemeResource CustomButtonBackGroundColor"} the color does not change but if I set  SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush the color changes. However, I cant change  SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush as this is defined in generic.xaml and will be used by other controls too.

Comment: @novice_coder If the color is not changing depending on the theme, then you are still doing something wrong somewhere. Could you maybe update your question with my answer and what your code looks like now?

Answer (score 0):

#2 would be optimal solution, but instead of just Red there needs to be {ThemeResource MyBrush} and MyBrush defined somewhere in ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries